# Android Parcelable readStringArray() java.lang.RuntimeException: bad array lengths on Nougat

Tags: android, parcelable, android-7.0-nougat

so the app i am working on ran into an issue, the app crashes **only** on Android 7 and up. from the logcat the error seems to happen on my parcelable class.

here is the point where the crash happens(the class which has the parcelable):

```
public class LookupCriteriaBean implements Parcelable, Serializable {
private String lookupCode;
private String lookupField;
private String lookupDisplayName;
private String lookupSearchValue;

public LookupCriteriaBean(){        
}

public LookupCriteriaBean(String s) {
    if (s == null || "".equals(s.trim()))
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid lookup criteria setting from server!");

    int idx = 0;
    String[] arrS = Tool.split(s, Global.DELIMETER_DATA);
    lookupCode = arrS[idx++];
    lookupField = arrS[idx++];
    lookupDisplayName = arrS[idx++];
}

public LookupCriteriaBean(Parcel in) {
    String[] arrS = new String[LookupCriteriaBean.class.getFields().length];
    in.readStringArray(arrS);

    int idx = 0;
    lookupCode = arrS[idx++];
    lookupField = arrS[idx++];
    lookupDisplayName = arrS[idx++];
}

public String getLookupCode() {
    return lookupCode;
}

public void setLookupCode(String lookupCode) {
    this.lookupCode = lookupCode;
}

public String getLookupField() {
    return lookupField;
}

public void setLookupField(String lookupField) {
    this.lookupField = lookupField;
}

public String getLookupDisplayName() {
    return lookupDisplayName;
}

public void setLookupDisplayName(String lookupDisplayName) {
    this.lookupDisplayName = lookupDisplayName;
}

public String toString() {
    return lookupDisplayName;
}

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeStringArray(new String[] { lookupCode, lookupField, lookupDisplayName });
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<LookupCriteriaBean> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<LookupCriteriaBean>() {

    public LookupCriteriaBean createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new LookupCriteriaBean(source);
    }

    public LookupCriteriaBean[] newArray(int size) {
        return new LookupCriteriaBean[size];
    }
};

public String getLookupSearchValue() {
    return lookupSearchValue;
}

public void setLookupSearchValue(String lookupSearchValue) {
    this.lookupSearchValue = lookupSearchValue;
    }
}
```

the line which triggers the crash is `in.readStringArray(arrS);`

the problem is the crash only happens on android 7 and above, it doesn't happen on any other devices i tested on, i have no idea what is causing this since the app runs fine on everything else except nougat devices.

here is the logcat output:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 3868): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868): Process: com.adins.msmfif, PID: 3868

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adins.msmfif/com.adins.msm.LookupActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: bad array lengths

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: bad array lengths

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at android.os.Parcel.readStringArray(Parcel.java:1125)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at com.adins.msm.model.LookupCriteriaBean.<init>(LookupCriteriaBean.java:33)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at com.adins.msm.model.LookupCriteriaBean$1.createFromParcel(LookupCriteriaBean.java:80)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at com.adins.msm.model.LookupCriteriaBean$1.createFromParcel(LookupCriteriaBean.java:1)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2470)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2364)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2778)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:2035)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2385)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2717)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:269)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Bundle.java:886)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at com.adins.msm.LookupActivity.initialize(LookupActivity.java:59)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at com.adins.msm.LookupActivity.onCreate(LookupActivity.java:49)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3868):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
```

any help is appreciated

Here is code from my activity that has the button which triggers the error

```
public class LookupActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private ArrayAdapter<LookupCriteriaBean> listAdapter;
private String lovType;
public final LayoutParams defLayout = new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

private QuestionBean bean = null;
private LinearLayout questionContainer;
private int totalCriteia = 1;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lookup);
    initialize();

    //---change to portrait mode---
//        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}

private void initialize() {
    setClickListener();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    ArrayList<LookupCriteriaBean> list = extras.getParcelableArrayList(
            Global.BUND_KEY_LOV_CRITERIA);
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<LookupCriteriaBean>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    listAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


     bean = DynamicSurveyActivity.getQuestionInFocus();
    lovType = bean.getAnswerType();

    if(bean.getTextMaxLength()!=0){
        totalCriteia = bean.getTextMaxLength();
    }
    questionContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sub_search_bar);
    questionContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


    for (int i = 0; i < totalCriteia; i++) {
        ViewGroup view = generateDropdownDesc(this,listAdapter, i);
        questionContainer.addView(view, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);               
    }
}


private void setClickListener() {
    Button btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {       
    Button btn = (Button) v;
    int id = btn.getId();
    if (R.id.search_button == id) {
        String lookupSearchValue = this.getSearchValue().trim();
    //  if (this.validateSearchValue(lookupSearchValue)) {

            LookupCriteriaBean lookupCriteriaBean[] =  new LookupCriteriaBean[totalCriteia];

            for (int i = 0; i < totalCriteia; i++) {

                LinearLayout qContainer = (LinearLayout) questionContainer.getChildAt(i);
                Spinner spinnerCriteria = (Spinner) qContainer.getChildAt(0);
                int posSpinner = spinnerCriteria.getSelectedItemPosition();

                EditText editText = (EditText) qContainer.getChildAt(1);

                LookupCriteriaBean beanCriteria = listAdapter.getItem(posSpinner);
                beanCriteria.setLookupSearchValue(editText.getText().toString().trim());

                lookupCriteriaBean[i] = beanCriteria;
            }

            Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            paramMap.put(Global.MAP_KEY_LOOKUP_CRITERIA, mergeLookupCriteriaBean(lookupCriteriaBean));

            if (Global.AT_LOV.equals(lovType)) {
                new LookupResultTask(this, getString(R.string.progressWait))
                    .execute(paramMap);
            }
            else if (Global.AT_LOV_W_FILTER.equals(lovType)) {
                LookupManager lookupManager = new LookupManager();
                QuestionBean qBean = DynamicSurveyActivity.getQuestionInFocus();
                List<QuestionBean> listOfQuestion = DynamicSurveyActivity.getListOfQuestion();

                lookupManager.setFilterValue(listOfQuestion, qBean);

                paramMap.put(Global.MAP_KEY_LOOKUP_FILTER, qBean.getLovFilters());
                new LookupResultTask(this, getString(R.string.progressWait))
                    .execute();
            }
    //  }
    }
}


private String getSearchValue() {
            String value = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < totalCriteia; i++) {        
        LinearLayout qContainer = (LinearLayout) questionContainer.getChildAt(i);               
        EditText editText = (EditText) qContainer.getChildAt(1);
        value = value+editText.getText().toString().trim(); 
    }

    return value;
}

private boolean validateSearchValue(String searchValue) {
    boolean valid = true;

    List<String> errMessage = new ArrayList<String>();

    if ("".equals(searchValue)) {
        errMessage.add(getString(R.string.lovHint) + " " + getString(R.string.msgRequired));
    }

    if (errMessage.size() > 0) {
        valid = false;

        String[] msg = (String[]) errMessage.toArray(new String[errMessage.size()]);
        String alert = Tool.implode(msg, "\n");
        Toast.makeText(this, alert, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }       

    return valid;
}

public LinearLayout generateDropdownDesc(Activity activity,
        ArrayAdapter<LookupCriteriaBean> listAdapter, int pos) {
    LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(activity);
    container.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    int totalOption = listAdapter.getCount();


        final String prompt = getString(R.string.lovCriteria);
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(activity);
        EditText desc = new EditText(activity);     
        desc.setHint(string.lovHint);
        spinner.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        spinner.setPrompt(prompt);

    if (pos < totalOption) {
        spinner.setSelection(pos);
    } else {
        int tempPos = (pos%totalOption);

        spinner.setSelection(tempPos);
    }


        container.addView(spinner, defLayout);
        container.addView(desc, defLayout);

    return container;
}

private LookupCriteriaBean mergeLookupCriteriaBean(LookupCriteriaBean[] lookupCriteriaBeanArray) {
    LookupCriteriaBean lookupCriteriaBean = new LookupCriteriaBean();

    lookupCriteriaBean.setLookupCode(lookupCriteriaBeanArray[0].getLookupCode());
    lookupCriteriaBean.setLookupDisplayName(lookupCriteriaBeanArray[0].getLookupDisplayName());
    lookupCriteriaBean.setLookupField(lookupCriteriaBeanArray[0].getLookupField());
    lookupCriteriaBean.setLookupSearchValue(lookupCriteriaBeanArray[0].getLookupSearchValue());


    if (lookupCriteriaBeanArray.length > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < lookupCriteriaBeanArray.length; i++) {
            String code = lookupCriteriaBean.getLookupCode();
            String field = lookupCriteriaBean.getLookupField();
            String searchValue = lookupCriteriaBean.getLookupSearchValue();

            lookupCriteriaBean.setLookupCode(code
                    + Global.DELIMETER_SUBSUBDATA
                    + lookupCriteriaBeanArray[i].getLookupCode());
            lookupCriteriaBean.setLookupField(field
                    + Global.DELIMETER_SUBSUBDATA
                    + lookupCriteriaBeanArray[i].getLookupField());
            lookupCriteriaBean.setLookupSearchValue(searchValue
                    + Global.DELIMETER_SUBSUBDATA
                    + lookupCriteriaBeanArray[i].getLookupSearchValue());

        }
    }

    return lookupCriteriaBean;

}
```

the button with R.id.search_button when pressed crashes on android 7 and up

hmmm... so i tried all sorts of things, even rewriting the code, still this problem persists, it might be something else in nougat that is causing this, any ideas?

Comment: Add logtags before you parcel the array. Check the length of it before it gets parceled, while and after it is parceled

Comment: Look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829975/android-parcelable-bad-array-lengths) - it is the same issue, but if your issue only triggers on 7.0+, there may be something else behind it. But look into the order and add debug tags!

Comment: [`writeStringArray(new String[] { lookupCode, lookupField, lookupDisplayName })` array should have length 3 .... and you are using `LookupCriteriaBean.class.getFields().length` which is 4](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java#L1124)

Comment: @LunarWatcher i already read the link you gave before asking this question and i tried reformatting my code as described, but still the problem persists, my app crashes on android 7 and up but works fine on anything below.

Comment: @Selvin i can confirm that `LookupCriteriaBean.class.getFields().length` does return 3 when i debugged my code, and if this was the case, my app would crash on all the other android versions too and give me a nullpointerexception.

Comment: @Selvin if it returns 3 on Android 6, why wouldn't it on Android 7

Comment: it doesn't matter ... http://ideone.com/FEja3F the number 3 is not comming from private fields it is comming from `LookupCriteriaBean .CREATOR` and Parcelable constatnts ... obviously it would be better to use constant  3 instead

Comment: @Selvin i do get your point but the debug does say that after `String[] arrS = new String[LookupCriteriaBean.class.getFields().length];` the debug value for arrS is  `String[3] [null,null,null]` i do agree it should return 4 but this works correctly, i must add that i am just assigned with trying to fix this issue in a big team and i have limited info as well on this regard on why it behaves like this, all i know is that the app crashes on that point on only android 7.0 and above, and works as intended in all versions under, i am as confused as you at this point.

Comment: @Selvin ahh if that is the case then... the code i have is already correct, although the question still remains on what is the cause of this error. i'll add the code from my activity, maybe it might help on diagnosing what is causing this.

Comment: @LunarWatcher seems like it is the same problem after all, although it is still a mystery why my code worked fine on older versions of android, which made me think too much and look into the wrong places, thanks for everyones help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after rewriting my code a few times ad referencing other answers with the same problem, splitting the array of string i used to seperate strings fixed this issue, althoug i still have no idea why `getStringArray(arrS)` would crash only on android 7 and up.

i do wonder why my code still runs on lower versions fine though.

so both seperating all the fields **and** accessing them in the correct order then it works.

here is my fixed code:

```
---------------snip---------------------------------

public LookupCriteriaBean(Parcel in) {
    lookupCode = in.readString();
    lookupField = in.readString();
    lookupDisplayName = in.readString();
    }

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(lookupCode);
    dest.writeString(lookupField);
    dest.writeString(lookupDisplayName);
}

-----------------snip--------------------------------
```

Answer (score -1):

**A small tip!**

You can use the following library, to simplify the use of parcelable.

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-Parceler

If you check www.parcelabler.com, this might be a solution

```
public class LookupCriteriaBean implements Parcelable, Serializable {
private String lookupCode;
private String lookupField;
private String lookupDisplayName;
private String lookupSearchValue;

public String getLookupSearchValue() {
    return lookupSearchValue;
}

public void setLookupSearchValue(String lookupSearchValue) {
    this.lookupSearchValue = lookupSearchValue;
    }

public String getLookupCode() {
    return lookupCode;
}

public void setLookupCode(String lookupCode) {
    this.lookupCode = lookupCode;
}

public String getLookupField() {
    return lookupField;
}

public void setLookupField(String lookupField) {
    this.lookupField = lookupField;
}

public String getLookupDisplayName() {
    return lookupDisplayName;
}

public void setLookupDisplayName(String lookupDisplayName) {
    this.lookupDisplayName = lookupDisplayName;
}

public String toString() {
    return lookupDisplayName;
}

//
//  Here is the implementation of parcelable
//
    protected LookupCriteriaBean(Parcel in) {
        lookupCode = in.readString();
        lookupField = in.readString();
        lookupDisplayName = in.readString();
        lookupSearchValue = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(lookupCode);
        dest.writeString(lookupField);
        dest.writeString(lookupDisplayName);
        dest.writeString(lookupSearchValue);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<LookupCriteriaBean> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<LookupCriteriaBean>() {
        @Override
        public LookupCriteriaBean createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new LookupCriteriaBean(in);
        }

        @Override
        public LookupCriteriaBean[] newArray(int size) {
            return new LookupCriteriaBean[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: NOTE: YOu cannot declare implementation of two objects with the same name unless you add the package/class it is nested in(depending on whether it is a standalone class or not)